# Query Governor Cost Limit relationship with Time

Tags: sql-server, resource-governor

Based on [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191219(v=sql.110).aspx), Query Governor `Cost Limit` refers to the `estimated elapsed time, in seconds`. This meets this [excerpt from the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Administrator's Pocket Consultant](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd421653.aspx) book.

Walking to the book [Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Unleashed, pages 30 and 31](http://books.google.pt/books?id=NeBPAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA1165&lpg=PA1165&dq=sql+server+query+governor+cost+time&source=bl&ots=kD_6IN2wEE&sig=XO-GQ-4hd3qX-BHXsOCxVFrXjYw&hl=pt-PT&sa=X&ei=SsERVMCpC5PxaKL0gogP&ved=0CFQQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=sql%20server%20query%20governor%20cost%20time&f=false), the `cost limit` is `proportional to the estimated time`, and one should apply a factor (K), to take into account the system's specifics, so it would be `K x time(s)`.

Now, if I take [this (somehow older) article](http://sqlmag.com/querying/estimating-query-costs), it feels like establishing a relationship between cost limit and time is not doable.

Can I say that in the real world, despite some more rare exceptions, the 2nd approach could be taken as a rule of thumb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Based on my notes from  SQL Server internals (by Kalen Delaney).... below is my understanding*

**Query Governor Cost limit** is the max no. of seconds that a query can run.

So, essentially :

- a non-zero or a negative value will disallow execution of any query that has an estimated cost exceeding that value.
- Zero which is default - turns off the query governor and all the queries are allowed to run without any time limit.

> Note that the value set for seconds isn’t clock-based. It corresponds to seconds on a specific hardware configuration used during product development, and the actual limit might be higher or lower on your machine.

Also, it should be noted that changing the `Query Governor Cost limit` will flush the entire plan cache resulting in generating a new plan afterwards.

Comment: +1 important note about flushing the plan cache! An important curiosity; though [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee343986(v=sql.100).aspx) states that issuing a RECONFIGURE will clear the cache plan, it becomes clear in [here](http://mattsql.wordpress.com/2012/06/25/dont-believe-everything-you-read-reconfigure-flushes-the-plan-cache/) that only some of them (in which the QG Cost limit is included) actually cause it.

Comment: @user16484 Yes, that 5-year old article could probably have a better qualifier on that bullet point. I've passed that info along to the author - whether he has any power to see a change through at this point is probably unlikely.